# Filter by an element inside a group in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table 
(
    the_debt_id varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    the_debt_pay_id varchar(8) NOT NULL, 
    the_debt_due date NOT NULL, 
    the_debt_paid timestamp NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES ('LMUS01', 'LMUS0100', '2020-03-02', '2020-03-01 06:59:32'),
       ('LMUS01', 'LMUS0101', '2020-04-02', '2020-04-01 06:29:53'),
       ('LMUS01', 'LMUS0102', '2020-05-02', '2020-04-01 02:28:41'),
       ('LMUS01', 'LMUS0103', '2020-06-02', '2020-05-18 11:17:20'),
       ('LMUS01', 'LMUS0104', '2020-07-02', '2020-05-18 11:07:01'),
       ('LMUS01', 'LMUS0105', '2020-08-02', '2020-08-02 11:22:04'), 
       ('LMUS02', 'LMUS0200', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03 09:34:20'),
       ('LMUS02', 'LMUS0201', '2020-02-02', '2020-01-31 06:58:18'),
       ('LMUS02', 'LMUS0202', '2020-03-02', '2020-03-02 07:30:59')
```

How can I filter by an element (let's say LMUS0103 and LMUS0202) inside of a group? For example I want all the records that are equal or less than the max `the_debt_due` in the group where the element falls. A group is a combination of `the_debt_id` and the date of `the_debt_paid`. This is the expected output:

```
the_debt_id    the_debt_pay_id    the_debt_due
LMUS01         LMUS0100           2020-03-02    ---> LMUS01&2020-03-01 group1
LMUS01         LMUS0101           2020-04-02    ---> LMUS01&2020-04-01 group2
LMUS01         LMUS0102           2020-05-02    ---> LMUS01&2020-04-01 group2
LMUS01         LMUS0103           2020-06-02    ---> LMUS01&2020-05-18 group3  
LMUS01         LMUS0104           2020-07-02    ---> LMUS01&2020-05-18 group3 max date of group
LMUS02         LMUS0200           2020-01-02    ---> LMUS02&2020-01-03 group1
LMUS02         LMUS0201           2020-02-02    ---> LMUS02&2020-01-31 group2
LMUS02         LMUS0202           2020-03-02    ---> LMUS02&2020-03-02 group3 max date of group
```

I have to group by `the_debt_id` and `the_debt_paid::date` for `the_debt_pay_id IN ('LMUS0103','LMUS0202')` but I can't figure it out how to get the max of that group. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: "Less than or equal to the max" describes all non-`NULL` values.

Comment: Hello @Gordon Linoff, is less than or equal to the max in the group where the element falls. For example for LMUS0103, it belongs to group 3, the max `the_debt_due` element in that group is 2020-07-02, so is all the elements equal or less than 2020-07-02, so that excludes the row where LMUS0105 is.